# Launching css in sequence with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to launch an animation with JQuery using .css. I want to turn letter left, then right, then again left and right while it will be moving up.

```
$('.envelope').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.list')
    .animate({top:'0px'},1000);
    $(this).find('.list').delay(100)
    .css({"-ms-transform":"rotate(-6deg)","-webkit-transform":"rotate(-6deg)","transform":"rotate(-6deg)"});
    $(this).find('.list').delay(200)
    .css({"-ms-transform":"rotate(6deg)","-webkit-transform":"rotate(6deg)","transform":"rotate(6deg)"});
    $(this).find('.list').delay(300)
    .css({"-ms-transform":"rotate(-6deg)","-webkit-transform":"rotate(-6deg)","transform":"rotate(-6deg)"});
    $(this).find('.list').delay(400)
    .css({"-ms-transform":"rotate(6deg)","-webkit-transform":"rotate(6deg)","transform":"rotate(6deg)"});
    });
```

[adding link](http://jsfiddle.net/eH6Xc/2/)

Comment: Is it lunch time already ?

Comment: Why not use css3 animations?

Comment: It's not clear to me what is wrong. Which behavior is not working for you?

Comment: Because Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the @keyframe rule or animation property.

Why letter is not turning left, right, left and right, but it is only turning right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery.queue for this

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

I can make you an example if you need one. Here is a good write up:

http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/06/22/how-to-use-custom-jquery-animation-queues/

The example is doing something very similar to what you are trying to accomplish. Let me know if you can't get this working. I can throw together a quick example for you.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery transit plugin is designed for exactly this! It is jQuery animation API compatible, but uses CSS transitions.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/